# How to reset snake in javafx game?

Tags: java, javafx, snake

I am making snake in javafx, I have completed my game, and I am trying to add a reset button in my game. When I click the reset key (ENTER), the game should reset,  but the arraylist that stores the rectangles that make up the snake does not reset. For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to make it work. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Code: https://pastebin.com/yiQi8DSU

Code:

```
package finalproject;



public class FinalProject extends Application {

Random rand = new Random();

Pane canvas;
Scene scene;
double points1[] = {100, 100, 1200, 100, 1200, 900, 100, 900,};
Polygon poly1;
Text Score, HighScore, GameOver, Reset, Time;
Font font1, font2;
Rectangle SnakeBody, Food, EndScreen, SpeedBoost, ScoreMultiplier;
ArrayList<Rectangle> Snakes;
int RIGHT = 0, UP = 1, LEFT = 2, DOWN = 3;
int facing = 0;
int rightSpeed = 0, upSpeed = 0, leftSpeed = 0, downSpeed = 0;
int SnakeSpeed = 4;
int score = 0;
int Multiplier = 0;
int Booster = 0;
int Score2 = 0;
//int timeCount = 2000;
// long second = 1000000000;

public void Objects() {

    facing = RIGHT;

    Food = new Rectangle(600, 600, 20, 20);
    Food.setStroke(Color.RED);
    Food.setFill(Color.RED);

    SpeedBoost = new Rectangle(4000, 4000, 20, 20);
    SpeedBoost.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
    SpeedBoost.setFill(Color.PURPLE);

    ScoreMultiplier = new Rectangle(4000, 4000, 15, 15);
    ScoreMultiplier.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
    ScoreMultiplier.setFill(Color.CHARTREUSE);

}

public void reset() {

    SnakeBody.setX(150);
    SnakeBody.setY(150);

    Food.setX(600);
    Food.setY(600);

    rightSpeed = 0;
    upSpeed = 0;
    leftSpeed = 0;
    downSpeed = 0;
    SnakeSpeed = 4;

    if (canvas.getChildren().contains(SpeedBoost)) {
        canvas.getChildren().remove(SpeedBoost);
    }

    if (canvas.getChildren().contains(ScoreMultiplier)) {
        canvas.getChildren().remove(ScoreMultiplier);
    }

    score = 0;
    Score.setText("Score: " + score);

    Snakes.clear();

    Objects();
    ;

}

private class Timer extends AnimationTimer {

    @Override

    public void handle(long l) {

        // Timer timer2 = new Timer();
        Shape overlap2 = Shape.intersect(SnakeBody, SpeedBoost);

        if (overlap2.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() > 0 || overlap2.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight() > 0) {

            SpeedBoost.setX(4000); //Moves the object outside of the canvas.
            SpeedBoost.setY(4000);

            Booster = 10;
        }

        Shape overlap3 = Shape.intersect(SnakeBody, ScoreMultiplier);

        if (overlap3.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() > 0 || overlap3.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight() > 0) {

            ScoreMultiplier.setX(4000); //Moves the object outside of the canvas.
            ScoreMultiplier.setY(4000);

            Multiplier = 10;

        }

        //Snake moving lines
        if (rightSpeed > 0 && facing != RIGHT) {

            facing = RIGHT;

        } else {

            for (int i = Snakes.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {

                Snakes.get(i).setX(Snakes.get(i - 1).getX());
                Snakes.get(i).setY(Snakes.get(i - 1).getY());

            }

        }

        SnakeBody.setX(SnakeBody.getX() + rightSpeed - leftSpeed);
        SnakeBody.setY(SnakeBody.getY() + downSpeed - upSpeed);

        //Boundaries for the snake
        if (SnakeBody.getX() <= 100 || SnakeBody.getY() <= 100) {

            if (!canvas.getChildren().contains(EndScreen)) {
                canvas.getChildren().addAll(EndScreen, GameOver);

            }

        }

        if (SnakeBody.getX() >= 1170 || SnakeBody.getY() >= 870) {

            if (!canvas.getChildren().contains(EndScreen)) {
                canvas.getChildren().addAll(EndScreen, GameOver);

            }
        }

        Shape overlap = Shape.intersect(SnakeBody, Food);

        if (overlap.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() > 0 || overlap.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight() > 0) {

            Food.setX(rand.nextInt(1200));
            Food.setY(rand.nextInt(900));

            if (Multiplier == 5) {

                Score2 = Score2 + 1;
                Score.setText("Score: " + Score2);

            } else {

                score = score + 1;
                Score.setText("Score: " + score);

            }

            if (score > 5) {

                if (!canvas.getChildren().contains(SpeedBoost)) {

                    SpeedBoost.setX(350);
                    SpeedBoost.setY(350);

                    canvas.getChildren().add(SpeedBoost);

                }
            }

            if (score >= 4) {

                if (!canvas.getChildren().contains(ScoreMultiplier)) {

                    ScoreMultiplier.setX(100);
                    ScoreMultiplier.setY(100);

                    canvas.getChildren().add(ScoreMultiplier);
                }
            }

            if (leftSpeed > 0) {

                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { //Adds 5x the rectangles, preventing the slow growing.

                    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(Snakes.get(Snakes.size() - 1).getX(), Snakes.get(Snakes.size() - 1).getY(), 30, 30);
                    Snakes.add(r);
                    r.setFill(Color.GOLD);
                    r.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
                    canvas.getChildren().addAll(r);

                }
            }

            if (rightSpeed > 0) {

                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

                    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(Snakes.get(Snakes.size() - 1).getX(), Snakes.get(Snakes.size() - 1).getY(), 30, 30);
                    Snakes.add(r);
                    r.setFill(Color.GOLD);
                    r.setStroke(Color.WHITE);

                    canvas.getChildren().addAll(r);
                }

            }

            if (upSpeed > 0) {

                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(Snakes.get(Snakes.size() - 1).getX(), Snakes.get(Snakes.size() - 1).getY(), 30, 30);

                    Snakes.add(r);
                    r.setFill(Color.GOLD);
                    r.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
                    canvas.getChildren().addAll(r);
                }

            }

            if (downSpeed > 0) {

                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(Snakes.get(Snakes.size() - 1).getX(), Snakes.get(Snakes.size() - 1).getY(), 30, 30);

                    Snakes.add(r);

                    r.setFill(Color.GOLD);
                    r.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
                    canvas.getChildren().addAll(r);
                }
            }

        }

        if (Food.getX() <= 100) {
            Food.setX(rand.nextInt(1200));

        }

        if (Food.getY() <= 100) {
            Food.setY(rand.nextInt(900));

        }

        if (Food.getX() >= 1170) {
            Food.setX(rand.nextInt(1200));

        }

        if (Food.getY() >= 870) {
            Food.setY(rand.nextInt(900));

        }

    }

}

public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    canvas = new Pane();
    scene = new Scene(canvas, 1300, 1300, Color.BLACK);
    Objects();

    /*Shape overlap5 = Shape.intersect(SnakeBody, Food);

    if (overlap5.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() > 0 || overlap5.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight() > 0) {

        timeCount = timeCount - 1;
        Time = new Text(700, 60, "Time Survived: " + timeCount);
        Time.setFont(font1);
        Time.setFill(Color.YELLOW);

    }*/
    EndScreen = new Rectangle(1300, 1300);
    EndScreen.setFill(Color.BLACK);

    poly1 = new Polygon(points1);
    poly1.setFill(Color.DARKBLUE);
    poly1.setStroke(Color.GREY);
    poly1.setStrokeWidth(3);

    font1 = Font.font("Arial", 24);
    font2 = Font.font("Arial", 48);

    GameOver = new Text(500, 500, "Game Over");
    GameOver.setFont(font2);
    GameOver.setFill(Color.RED);

    //Reset = new Text(650, 650, "You survived for: " + timeCount);
    Score = new Text(250, 60, "Score: " + score);
    Score.setFont(font1);
    Score.setFill(Color.YELLOW);

    HighScore = new Text(700, 60, "High Score: ");
    HighScore.setFont(font1);
    HighScore.setFill(Color.YELLOW);

    canvas.getChildren().addAll(poly1, Score, Food);
    Snakes = makeSnakeBodies();
    canvas.getChildren().addAll(Snakes);

    scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

        public void handle(KeyEvent evt) {

            if (Multiplier == 10) {

                Score2 = score * 2; //Multiplies score

                Multiplier = 5; //Any value other than 10

            }

            if (Booster == 10) {

                if (evt.getCode().equals(KeyCode.Q)) {

                    SnakeSpeed = 15;

                }

                if (evt.getCode().equals(KeyCode.A)) {

                    SnakeSpeed = 4;

                }
            }

            if (evt.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {


                reset();

                //AnimationTimer class1 = new Timer(); // Code resets the Objects() method but not the animation timer class
            }

            if (evt.getCode().equals(KeyCode.RIGHT) && leftSpeed == 0) {

                rightSpeed = SnakeSpeed;
                upSpeed = 0;
                leftSpeed = 0;
                downSpeed = 0;

            } else if (evt.getCode().equals(KeyCode.UP) && downSpeed == 0) {

                upSpeed = SnakeSpeed;
                rightSpeed = 0;
                leftSpeed = 0;
                downSpeed = 0;

            } else if (evt.getCode().equals(KeyCode.DOWN) && upSpeed == 0) {

                downSpeed = SnakeSpeed;
                rightSpeed = 0;
                leftSpeed = 0;
                upSpeed = 0;

            } else if (evt.getCode().equals(KeyCode.LEFT) && rightSpeed == 0) {

                leftSpeed = SnakeSpeed;
                rightSpeed = 0;
                upSpeed = 0;
                downSpeed = 0;

            }

        }

    });

    primaryStage.setTitle("Snake");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.start();

}

public ArrayList<Rectangle> makeSnakeBodies() {

    ArrayList<Rectangle> joints = new ArrayList<>();

    int x = 150;
    int y = 150;

    SnakeBody = new Rectangle(x, y, 30, 30);
    SnakeBody.setFill(Color.GOLD);
    SnakeBody.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
    joints.add(SnakeBody);

    return joints;

}

}
```

---

If you need specific sections of code, I can post them separately. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the Snake body to your canvas but you never remove it. That's why `reset()` won't clear your Snake.

You're adding the Snake body within your `start()` method:

```
Snakes = makeSnakeBodies(); 
canvas.getChildren().addAll(Snakes); //HERE you add the Snakes
```

now the `Snakes` are added to your `Canvas` (well: `Pane`) but they are never removed.

### Solution:

you should remove the `Snakes` later in your `reset()` method as well:

```
public void reset() {
    SnakeBody.setX(150);
    SnakeBody.setY(150);
    ...
    if (canvas.getChildren().contains(SpeedBoost)) {
        canvas.getChildren().remove(SpeedBoost);
    }
    ...
    canvas.getChildren().removeAll(Snakes); //HERE you remove the Snakes
    ...
}
```